# Jenkins Declarative: Create global variables based from conditions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to ask on how I can I declare global variable USE "**NON-PROD**" if the parameter passed to jenkins is either "**dev**" or "**qa**" then "**PROD**" if the parameter passed to jenkins is either "**uat**" or "**staging**". Here is the full details of condition

```
IF ENV = dev OR qa 
  then 
    USE = NON-PROD
ELSE IF ENV = uat OR staging 
   then 
    USE = PROD
```

here is my jenkins setup

Jenkins PARAMETER Settings

[image]

This is so far the test declarative script I used however not lucky to get the expected response. Im not also sure yet if the **ELSE-IF** condition is fine (for uat or staging)

```
def USE
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Declare Vars') {

        when {
          expression { params.ENV == 'qa'  || params.ENV == 'dev'  }
        }
        steps {
          USE = "NON-PROD"
        }

    }

    stage('Check Vars') {
      steps {
        sh """#!/bin/bash +x
          echo USE = ${USE}
        """
      }

    }

  }
}
```

This is the Error I'm getting

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 12: Expected a step @ line 12, column 11.
             USE = "NON-PROD"
             ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: It does not seem like your pipeline needs these extra variables. Given the question as presented, you could do this quite easily with only the `params` map inputs.

Comment: Please edit your question to add error information. You will propably get an error at this line: `USE = "NON-PROD"`, which requires a `script` block.

Comment: zett42 - I just added the error, I was on this understanding that the USE="NON-PROD" script block is the statement to declare the variable once the when expression is true

Comment: Matt Schuchard - I need the variable cause the "NON-PROD" value will be used on the next stages of the pipeline (I just didn't include the next pipelines)

Comment: @Lagot Outside of a `script{ }` block you can only call functions (aka steps). When you need flow control of individual steps or assign variables, a `script{ }` block is necessary. The answer of vijay shows this very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below would work. A simple `if..else` condition will do.

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   parameters {
      choice choices: ['UAT', 'STAG', 'DEV', 'QA'], description: '', name: 'chooseEnvironment'
    }

   stages {
        stage('Set ') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "${params.chooseEnvironment}"
                    if ( "${chooseEnvironment}" == 'DEV' || "${chooseEnvironment}" == 'QA' ) {
                       env.USE = "NON-PROD"
                    } else if ("${chooseEnvironment}" == 'UAT' || "${chooseEnvironment}" == 'STAG') {
                       env.USE = "PROD"
                    } else {
                        echo "No environment selected. Exit the build"
                        sh "exit 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        stage('Check Vars'){
            steps{
                echo "Environment choosen is ${env.USE}"
               // your-other-shell actions. Address the variable with ${env.USE}
            }
        }
    }     
}
```